# Int to 'SecTrustResultType'

Tags: xcode8, swift2

I'm a beginner to Swift and I'm trying to run Swift 2.3 code in Xcode 8.0

```
var result: SecTrustResultType = 0 
SecTrustEvaluate(trust, &result)
```

Error message:  Cannot convert value of type 'int' to specified type 'SecTrustResultType'

I asked this question before and it was marked a duplicate, but the link to the similar question didn't exactly help me.
[Cannot convert value of type 'int' to specified type 'SecTrustResultType'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42141973/cannot-convert-value-of-type-int-to-specified-type-sectrustresulttype)

Answer (score 0):

SecTrustResultType is likely an enum. Check the Swift language book (freely available on the AppStore) to see how you initialise an enum. That's a basic language feature that you *must learn*, so it's pointless to tell you for this specific case.